# Shortcut for command line directory change cd in Windows?

Tags: directory, cmd, windows-vista, cd

I use Windows Vista and I was wondering if there was a shortcut to open the command line directly in the current directory (the one that has the focus). It is actually quite painful to copy/paste each time the current directory in the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold down shift and right click in the directory. The menu that pops up will have the option to open a command prompt there.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold down shift while right-clicking the folder and one of the additional options will be "Open Command Window Here".

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that I want to create a shortcut command for "`cd C:\wamp64\www`". For example I want to do something that whenever I type `www` in command line and I hit *Enter* then that `cd` command gets executed.

**My command is :** `cd C:\wamp64\www`

**Shortcut command should be** : `www`

So in order to do this, follow these steps.

**Step 1:**
*Create an empty folder*

You need to create a folder in somewhere that you like, for example I created a folder called "Aliases" directly in Local Disk (C) and inside this folder now I can create some *bat files* for different shortcut commands.

**Step 2**
*Create a bat file*

Since I want my shortcut command to be `www` I need to create a file called `www.bat` and inside this file you need to have following codes:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D "C:\wamp64\www"
CMD
```

**Step 3**
*Edit Environment Variables*

And now you need to go to Edit Environment Variables and add `C:\Aliases` (The folder you created first) in your Path
(Since you only need to do it once I did not consider this as a separate step)

**DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART YOUR TERMINAL**
So now, just restart your Terminal and type `www` and hit Enter and there you go... Now current folder just changed